# Prestashop back office problems

Tags: prestashop, mamp

I installed Prestashop in my local machine with MAMP and installation works but when I go in the BO I have a lot of displays problem's that means that I can't use the BO...

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade your PHP version to 7.2:

[image: PHP compatibility]
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/#php-compatibility-chart